# Why StackLayout's BackgroundColor overrides Labels color?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-color

Here is relevent code:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = new Color(245, 240, 236)
        };

        Grid top = new Grid
        {
            ...
        };

        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            ...
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Label name = getLabel("Worksheet " + i);
            name.TextColor = Color.Black;
            grid.Children.Add(name, 0, i);

            Label date = getLabel("Opened by me " + new DateTime(2016, 1, i + 1 % 30).ToString("dd MMM yyy"));
            grid.Children.Add(date, 1, i);

            Label dots = getLabel("dots");
            grid.Children.Add(dots, 2, i);
        }

        Label menu = getTopLabel("menu");
        Label header = getTopLabel("Worksheets");
        header.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label));
        Label plus = getTopLabel("plus");
        Label edit = getTopLabel("edit");

        top.Children.Add(menu, 0, 0);
        top.Children.Add(header, 1, 0);
        top.Children.Add(plus, 2, 0);
        top.Children.Add(edit, 3, 0);

        stack.Children.Add(top);
        stack.Children.Add(grid);

        ...
    }

    private Label getLabel(string text)
    {
        return new Label
        {
            ...
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };
    }

    private Label getTopLabel(string text)
    {
        return new Label
        {
            ...
            BackgroundColor = new Color(227, 49, 35),
            TextColor = Color.Black
        };
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run the application, all the grids are displayed with one background color defined in StackLayout. It ignores all other color definition.
How I can define background color for layout but keep backgroun colors for cells of the grid?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `StackLayout` is not overriding anything here.

Xamarin.Forms provides its own [`Color`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/925fc0aa588a060eb23fa16c1d225dd030012c23/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Color.cs) class, which is **very misleading here** in my eyes. The constructor, that you used for creating a color takes double values as parameters called `r`, `g` and `b`. Unluckily it does not expext values between `0` and `255`, but values from `0.0` and `1.0`.  It is very confusing and took me an hour to find out...

So when working with RGB colors, simply use the `Color.FromRgb()` method when setting the `BackgroundColor` property in your code.

```
private Label getTopLabel(string text)
{
    return new Label
    {
        ...
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(227, 49, 35),
        TextColor = Color.Black
    };
}
```